# Remove Non Breaking Space from Pagination Jquery

Tags: jquery

Just when I thought I was done, I found in between my selected pagination '5' for example below, double hard coded non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;`. I don't have access in the cms to override this, so jquery is required.

What is the solution to be sure the pagination gets selected, not the `&nbsp;`. Please check out the fiddle so you can demo the exact experience.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/9AMnU/2/

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">4</a>
&nbsp;5&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.example.com">6</a>
```

This jquery cleans up and span tags around the pagination

```
$('.pag').each(function () {
  $(this).contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) !== '' 
  }).first().wrap('<div/>').parent().html(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/(\w)/, '<span>$1</span>')
      }).replaceWith(function () {
        return this.innerHTML;
      })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
$('.pag').each(function () {
  $(this).contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) !== '' 
  }).first().wrap('<div/>').parent().html(function (i, v) {

        v= v.replace("&nbsp;","");

        return v.replace(/(\w)/, '<span>$1</span>')
      }).replaceWith(function () {
        return this.innerHTML;
      })
})
```

i changed

```
v= v.replace("&nbsp;","");
```

**`UPDATE`**

try this

```
v= v.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"");
```

to remove multiple occurrences instead of rewriting the above code twice  .

Comment: when i doubled it up, like this, then it got rid of all the non breaking spaces http://jsfiddle.net/9AMnU/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

to remove spaces both at starting and ending